# PHP/MySQLremove single quotes form echo

Tags: php, mysql, echo, quotes

I'm trying to echo from a list of Companies.
But i cant get rid of the single quotes?
I found a lot of these questions already online, but none worked...

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4ugv.jpg)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label>Kunde</label>
        <?php
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $useractive = $_SESSION['id'];
            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT user.id, customer.customer_id, customer.customer_name
                                FROM user JOIN customer ON user.id = customer.customer_id
                                WHERE customer.customer_id=$useractive
                                ORDER BY customer.customer_id";

            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        ?>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" name="timer_kunde">
      <option></option>
            <?php
                $row = str_replace("'", "", $query);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                echo "<option value='".$row['customer_name']."'>'".$row['customer_name']."'</option>";
                }
            ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am also wondering, why does the echo only work if the "customer_name" is setup twice?
It only echoes once with this code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put your code in the question

Comment: why your replacing single quotes on $query variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_replace()` function to replace single quote('') from the string:

Use this: `str_replace("'","",$string);`

But for the exact solution of the question put your code here.

Comment: str_replace() function only works for the string, not for the $query, it's a wrong approach to implementing.
 Please tell me what you want in the above code??

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

your replacing single quotes on `$query` variable

> NOTE : you need to pass the string which is `$row['customer_name']`

```
    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $val= str_replace("'","",$row['customer_name']);
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $val ?>"><?php echo $val?></option>
    <?php

    }
    ?>
```